# Non Techie User Ad hoc LINQ query builder

Tags: linq

I am looking for a third party component which allows a non technical user to create simple adhoc LINQ queries by dragging and dropping the available fields and run it against a data model that I will be populating using Entity Framework. I've used http://devtools.korzh.com/eq/dotnet/ component previously to generate adhoc SQL queries but I want something similar for LINQ.

I am looking for only simple query generator, the most complex queries will include group by on couple of columns with summation on say revenue field(Or any measure field).

Do any of you guys know of any visually appealing tool already available in the market? If not then may be suggest an approach on how I can build it myself!

Many Thanks

Mithun

Answer (score 1):

Best I have seen is [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), its not the best "visual" query builder out there but it is pretty easy to test out LINQ queries.

[image]
<sub>(source: [linqpad.net](http://www.linqpad.net/linqpadscreen.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I know and use LINQPad, it's a very good tool for someone technical like us. But I am looking for a drag and drop kind of tool for end users who have no clue what LINQ is, and behind the scenes that tool should generate LINQ query, so I can capture the query string and do whatever I have to do with it. I've googled/binged a lot to find something but unfortunately I couldn't find any. I might just have to write my own I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Actually EasyQuery will support LINQ queries in upcoming version 3.4.0. 
You can contact the support team to get access to this functionality on BETA stage.